# Is it possible (as of June 2018) to successfully run the Google Assistant SDK and related features on Windows?

Tags: windows, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I set up Google Assistant (henceforth "GA") on my Mac with next to zero issues. I'm able to talk to the machine and see instantaneous speech to text translation, along with accurate answers to most of my questions.

Unfortunately this hasn't worked nearly as well in windows, and I can't get GA successfully installed on my Windows machine (which I have to use for work).

Is it even possible to run GA on Windows, natively? (I understand that it might be possible with an emulator).

So far I've see quite a few threads and tutorials, but no evidence of success.

Additionally, it seems that some of the GA libraries are probably not written for/compatible for Windows.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GA library need linux-armv7l and linux-x86_64 but no problem with the GA service.

Comment: Thank you! Figured it was something like that.

Comment: I think I need the GA library to RUN GA on my Windows machine, so I guess GA is out.

Comment: Nope, you are not forced to use the library, the library is only in python, how do you think c++ devs do to use it ? Use the GA service.